# How to i style hyperlinks separately from javascript or css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

how to i style the hyperlinks separately from javascript or css? But I don't want to create a new class or id for each one. I have tried and searched before i asked this question but I do not know the right terminalogy, sorry for my bad English

edit:

what i meant to say is that for 2 hyperlinks (for example, point is just difference):

```
<a href=https://www.google.com>google</a>
<a href=www.google.com>google, no http</a>
```

to be style different but only if the hyperlinks are different type

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: why did i get 2 less points?

Comment: @Paulie_D ok thank you i will try make the question better. thank you

Comment: In you're example they are the same type because they point to www.google.com or they are different because one don't have https?

Comment: jcubic you are right the 1st one is different because it has the S but that is one just example of it but yes that is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you're trying to do is style hyperlinks differently, depending on the type of hyperlink it is, or the location to which it points. CSS has these cool things called Attribute Selectors that allow you to do just that!

I wrote a blog post a few months ago (now merged with my new blog) that has a simple example on how you can style all httpS links differently.

```css
a
{
 color: green;
}

a[href^=https]
{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>This is an external link: <a href="https://www.twitter.com/ALMSTJSON">ALMSTJSON</a></p>
<p><a href="#">This is an internal link.</a></p>
```

Source: https://www.jase.blog/posts/post?id=148&title=How-to-Style-Internal-and-External-Links-Differently-with-Attribute-Selectors

Comment: thank you Jason i am try this now but it looks like i want it like this

Comment: Jason how can i use this i am confused?

Comment: Um, can you show me your code? That way I can see exactly what you're trying to do. In the meantime, try placing the CSS code above in your CSS file somewhere, or somewhere within the `<style>` tags, if you have them. If that doesn't work, then I will need to see your code (both HTML and CSS, please).

Comment: i think i got it to work propyl now for the S part not for the other types of difference but thank you because i think i can find way to do the other part by my self i will tell you

Comment: @rgbhex Ok, please let me know how it goes. And post your code as well if you need further help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it by applying elements level css like this

```css
a {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Normal Text</p>
  <p><a href="#"> This is hyperlink </a></p>
  <p><a href="#"> This is another hyperlink </a></p>
  <p><a href="#"> This is another hyperlink </a></p>
  <p> <a href="#"> This is another hyperlink </a></p>
  <p><span> Normal Text</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you Sanchit i didn't know i can put a in p. i still have lot to learn!